# Save Feature Map from a convolutional layer as Images - Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, feature-extraction, conv-neural-network

I would like to save the feature map produced by one of the convolutional layers as png images. I am already able to visualize it on **tensorboard** but I did not find any way to save them.

1. There is any way to save the images visualized in tensorboard using `tf.image_summary('conv1/features', features)`?

I also tried to convert the feature tensor in a NumPy array (using `features.eval()`) in order to save it using PIL.
Now, when I use `eval()` I am getting the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [1,227,227,3]
```

This because it passes the tensors as input to the Graph, but I want just to convert it in a NumPy array. I also tried to reset the graph using `tf.reset_default_graph()` but this time I get the error:

```
ValueError: ... the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph.
```

2. How can I store the feature map (a tensor of shape (256, 13, 13, 1), 256 images 13x13x1) as images on my filesystem?

Comment: I partially solved the second part using `features = features.eval(feed_dict={x:[im1]}) where x` where x is my placeholder `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,) + xdim)` and `xdim = zeros((1, 227,227,3)).astype(float32).shape[1:]`

Comment: For saving images from tensors, you can try scikit [imsave](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imsave)

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpuful!